# Setting user account in IIS 6.0 application pool

Tags: c#, iis-6

I'm creating a application pool in iis 6.0 using code, but haven't found a way of setting the user account in an application pool (default is network service). How do you set the user account that is going to be used in an application pool using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do an

```
InvokeSet("WAMUserName", new Object[] { "username" })
```

on the ApplicationPool instance

-edit: see this related question: [How can I change the username/password of an ApplicationPool in IIS from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662634/how-can-i-change-the-username-password-of-an-applicationpool-in-iis-from-c)