# How can I change the username and password of an application pool using the .NET ApplicationPool class?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, iis-7.5

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662634/how-can-i-change-the-username-password-of-an-applicationpool-in-iis-from-c) article but it doesn't appear to use the ApplicationPool class described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Feels like this is something simple I'm missing.

Also, in case anyone feels like being extra helpful, I'm trying to accomplish this in a PowerShell script that can basically take a list of application pool names and set their credentials using a script.  I can obviously derive this from a straight C# implementation, however.

Thanks!

Comment: tried taking a look and got this far

import WebAdministration

$appPool = Get-Item '.\AppPools\ASP.NET v4.0'


$appPool.processModel.Attributes.Item(1).Value = "domain\test user"
$appPool.processModel.Attributes.Item(2).Value = "password"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the ProcessModel property:

```
using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{  
    ApplicationPool pool = serverManager.ApplicationPools["YourAppPool"];

    pool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;  
    pool.ProcessModel.UserName = @"TheUser";  
    pool.ProcessModel.Password = @"ThePassword";  

    serverManager.CommitChanges();  
}
```