# How to programmatically set App Pool Identity on IIS 8

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-8, application-pool

I'm running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.  I have IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility installed.  I have been trying to figure out how to change the App Pool Identity for IIS 8 with .Net 4.5 - all of the examples I found are for IIS 6 and 7.

Here is what I have:

```
public class InternetInformationServices
{
    public void SetApplicationPoolIdentity(string appPoolName, string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string metabasePath = "IIS://Localhost/W3SVC/AppPools";

            DirectoryEntry myAppPool;
            DirectoryEntry apppools = new DirectoryEntry(metabasePath);
            myAppPool = apppools.Children.Find(appPoolName, "IIsApplicationPool");
            myAppPool.Invoke("AppPoolIdentityType", new Object[] { 3 });
            myAppPool.Invoke("WAMUserName", new Object[] { domain + @"\" + username });
            myAppPool.Invoke("WAMUserPass", new Object[] { password });
            myAppPool.Invoke("SetInfo", null);
            myAppPool.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is able to find the App Pool, but as soon as I invoke it to set any of the following:

```
 myAppPool.Invoke("AppPoolIdentityType", new Object[] { 3 });
 myAppPool.Invoke("WAMUserName", new Object[] { domain + @"\" + username });
 myAppPool.Invoke("WAMUserPass", new Object[] { password });
```

I get the following error on the inner exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, or what is different with IIS 8.

Comment: You should get rid of that try/catch block. It has no benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ( from [How can I change the username/password of an ApplicationPool in IIS from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662634/how-can-i-change-the-username-password-of-an-applicationpool-in-iis-from-c?rq=1) )

```
myAppPool .Properties["AppPoolIdentityType"].Value = 3;
myAppPool .Properties["WAMUserName"].Value = Environment.MachineName + @"\" + username;
myAppPool .Properties["WAMUserPass"].Value = password;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to get this type of code snippet for most things in the iis metabase. we use this process to script automation at my office.

**I'll use your question about specifying credentials as an example:**

open inetmgr first and then select your hostname and then open the config. 
[image]

then select the system.applicationHost/applicationPools config section and expand the app pools collection, when done exit the window: 
[image]
select the appropriate application pool, change the identitytype to specific user and set the user and pass.[image]

Now click on Generate script, do not apply changes.[image]

FINALLY: All the api goodness you wanted, including your sample code: [image]

Comment: Oh could I did not know I could do this.  Thanks for this handy trick.